Lazy merging the Iterator of infinite Iterator-s
Suppose I have an infinite timed stream (Iterator) of some Point-s.
The Point-s in the stream are guaranteed to have properly ordered timings.
struct Point {
    payload: char,
    label: char,
    time: u32,
}

// This is just an example, the real
// stream is out of control
// 
// generate 4 parallel infinite tracks
let tracks = (0..).flat_map(move |i| {
    (0..4)
        .map(|j| {
            let label = labels_iter.next().unwrap();
            let payload = payloads_iter.next().unwrap();
            Point {
                payload,
                label,
                time: 5 * i + j,
            }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
});

Every Point belongs to some category determined by the field label.
I do not know in advance the number of categories in a whole stream,
but this number is guaranteed to be finite.
My workflow looks like the following:

split the whole stream into sub-streams by categories;


fn partition<I, T, F>(
  iter: I,
  predicate: F,
) -> (
  impl CloneableIterator<Item = T>,
  impl CloneableIterator<Item = T>,
)
where
  I: Iterator<Item = T> + Clone,
  F: Fn(&T) -> bool + Clone + 'static,
{
  let f = predicate.clone();
  let left = iter.clone().filter(move |x| f(x));
  let right = iter.filter(move |x| !predicate(x));
  (left, right)
}

fn split_by_label(
  it: impl Iterator<Item = Point> + Clone + 'static,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = (char, impl Iterator<Item = Point>)> + Clone {
  let mut stream = {
      let it: Box<dyn CloneableIterator<Item = Point>> = Box::new(it);
      Some(it.peekable())
  };

  iter::from_fn(move || {
      let mut current_stream = stream.take()?;
      let head = current_stream.peek()?;
      let label = head.label;

      let (this_instrument, other) = partition(current_stream, move |e| e.label == label);
      let other: Box<dyn CloneableIterator<Item = Point>> = Box::new(other);
      stream = Some(other.peekable());
      Some((label, this_instrument))
  })
}
let splitted = split_by_label(tracks);


process every category's stream individually;

/// An example of by-category processing
fn process_splitted(
  tracks: impl Iterator<Item = (char, impl Iterator<Item = Point>)> + Clone,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = (char, impl Iterator<Item = Point>)> + Clone {
  tracks.map(|(label, track)| {
      (
          label,
          track.map(|p| Point {
              payload: p.payload.to_ascii_lowercase(),
              ..p
          }),
      )
  })
}

let processed = process_splitted(splitted);


merge the substreams back into the single stream preserving timed ordering.

fn merge_tracks(
  tracks: impl Iterator<Item = impl Iterator<Item = Point> + 'static>,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = Point> {
  let init: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Point>> = Box::new(iter::empty());
  tracks.fold(init, |acc, track| {
      let acc = acc.merge_by(track, |p1, p2| p1.time < p2.time);
      Box::new(acc)
  })
}

let merged = merge_tracks(processed.map(|(_label, p)| p));

——-
The first two steps work with the help of CloneableIterator subtrait of Iterator.
However, I cannot properly implement the last step, because
the construction (not consuming) of the final iterator cannot complete
due to the usage of combination of Iterator::fold and Itertools::merge_by.
Is there some way to do the last step lazily so that I be able
to actually consume the final iterator?
Full playground example is here.

This seems impossible to achieve without knowing the categories beforehand. Why are you splitting the stream per category, rather than just processing each Point on demand (based on the category it belongs to) in the order they are produced?
